# Spark append mode for partitioned text file fails with SaveMode.Append - IOException File already Exists

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Something simple as writing partitioned text files fails.

```
dataDF.write.partitionBy("year", "month", "date").mode(SaveMode.Append).text("s3://data/test2/events/")
```

Exception -

```
16/07/06 02:15:05 ERROR datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer: Aborting task.
java.io.IOException: File already exists:s3://path/1839dd1ed38a.gz
 at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.create(S3NativeFileSystem.java:614)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:913)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:894)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:791)
 at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.create(EmrFileSystem.java:177)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:135)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextOutputWriter.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:156)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextRelation$$anon$1.newInstance(DefaultSource.scala:125)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:129)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.newOutputWriter$1(WriterContainer.scala:424)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:356)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/07/06 02:15:05 INFO output.DirectFileOutputCommitter: Nothing to clean up on abort since there are no temporary files written
16/07/06 02:15:05 ERROR datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201607060215_0004_m_001709_3 aborted.
16/07/06 02:15:05 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1709.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 12093)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:414)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File already exists:s3://path/a984-1839dd1ed38a.gz
 at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.create(S3NativeFileSystem.java:614)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:913)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:894)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:791)
 at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.create(EmrFileSystem.java:177)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:135)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextOutputWriter.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:156)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextRelation$$anon$1.newInstance(DefaultSource.scala:125)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:129)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.newOutputWriter$1(WriterContainer.scala:424)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:356)
 ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After lot of wasted man hours, answering my question with solution that worked for me, among other trouble shootings.

TLDR;
Set spark.speculation to false, as follow :

```
conf = new SparkConf().set(“spark.speculation“,”false”)
```

More details [here](http://www.confusedcoders.com/bigdata/spark/spark-append-mode-for-partitioned-text-file-fails-with-savemode-append-ioexception-file-already-exists) and [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1764/ioexception-writing-parquet-file-with-savemodeappe.html).

Comment: What is the version of Spark when you ran into this problem?