# spark savemode.append file already exists

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, emr, orc

we experiencing rare issues with writing to S3 inside Spark jobs in Amazon EMR (5.13). Here is the part of the log:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 2.0 
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File already exists:s3://*****/part-00003-58fe4151-60d6-4605-b971-21dbda31678b-c000.snappy.orc
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.create(S3NativeFileSystem.java:507)
...
```

It looks very strange because we use SaveMode.Append to save the dataset:

```
input.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).orc(path);
```

I googled a bit and found a couple of the same issues (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218853/spark-append-mode-for-partitioned-text-file-fails-with-savemode-append-ioexcep?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) but we don't use the spark.speculation, so I just have no idea what happened.

Can anybody suggest me where I can search the roots of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the EMR code is closed so I cannot comment on its internals. I do know that without a consistently layer, committing work against S3 is prone to rare failures, either visible (here), or simply losing data as a fake directory rename misses new files when it lists things under a path.

Try using local hdfs as a destination, or consistent EMR.